# Scrapy: How to see the XPath when the website doesn't have a right click enabled

Tags: macos, google-chrome, scrapy

Well, I have solved this in the past, but I don't remember anymore.

I have a website which I can't click right click on it.

I want to see some XPath. I could open the developer tool now, but my question is that in the past there was a shortcut for Mac OS where it not just open the developer tool, but it also allows you to see the XPath directly when you hover over the element in the HTML.

Do you know that option please?

Comment: I don't know about that option, but the shortcut for the developer tools is Cmd+Alt+I. It's in the "view" menu in "developers".

Comment: @Pekka웃 no not that one, there is a shortcut i am sure, i used to use it when i was crawling that website two months ago, but now i forgot, i found it in a question in StackOverFlow, but i couldn't find the question neither.